# What does 'OP' mean?

Tags: support, status-completed

I guess from the context OP means the person asking the question, but I'm still wondering: what does 'OP' stand for? Is it an acronym of something?

Maybe I did not look well, but I did not find it in the GIS SE help center by entering 'OP' in the search box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am glad that you asked because the use of the abbreviation OP on Stack Exchange sites is something that I would like to see diminish.

Sometimes people use it to mean **Original Post**.

Sometimes people use it to mean **Original Poster** and, when they do, they may be [talking about the asker or the answerer of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261137/215590).

The abbreviation seems to be commonly understood in the IT world but the Stack Exchange network has many more sites than just Stack Overflow and other sites that are more "computing" oriented, and I do not think the continued use of OP is an inclusive one.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :) Somebody in the thread suggests one should rather use Asker and stop saying OP :)

Comment: So, following on from this, would you say that when editing questions, or answers where "OP" is present, it would be good practice to change it at the same time?

Comment: @MartinHügi It is not something that I recall ever having done but if I saw it as a suggested edit I think it is something that I would approve. I'm certainly happy to see anyone else take the lead on making our Q&As clearer in that regard.